# Dynamic Array Allocation, pass by value, out of range

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have two questions about dynamic allocated array. I have looked up some similar questions but still didn't find the answer.

1. Pass by value

   Basically, I write two functions, one for allocation and another for free memory. When I pass the array pointer by value, the allocation function didn't work (as expected) but the free function works. And in my naive understanding, even if we pass the array pointer by value, the allocation should still work since it allocates a memory at the same memory address the value represented. And if we refers to that address later, regardless of the variable name, we should be able to find that space. This is the code:

   ```
   void main()
   {
      int * array;
      allocation(array);
      deallocation(array);
   }

   void allocation(int * result)
   {
      result = malloc(8293 * sizeof(result));
   }

   void deallocation(int * result)
   {
      free(result);
   }
   ```

   For deallocation test, I declared int * array = malloc(23123* sizeof(int)) in the main function instead of using allocation function. Again, the deallocation works.
2. Out of range access.

   ```
   void main()
   {
       FILE * fp = fopen("sometext.txt");

       int * A = malloc(100 * sizeof(int));
       int * B = malloc(200 * sizeof(int));

    /* Now I accidentally access A from 0-199 and B from 0-999 using a for loop*/
       char buffer[500];
       int i,x;

        for (i=0; i<200; i++)
        {  
             fgets(fp,buffer);
             sccanf(buffer, "%d", x);
             A[i]=x;
        }

        for (i=0; i<1000; i++)
        {  
             fgets(fp,buffer);
             sccanf(buffer, "%d", x);
             B[i]=x;
        }
   }
   ```

   Both for loop should not work. However, I somehow get passed the first loop and only get seg fault in the second loop. And the error I get is traced back to sccanf (I tested the code without assign any value to A or B, and it works. So the sccanf statement should be fine.) The gdb error message is : isoc99_sscanf (s=,  format=).

The full bt message is below, SOL[] is my B[] here and the actual sscanf read more variables. I can post full code if you are interested.

```
  #0  0x00007ffff7a6869b in _IO_vfscanf_internal (s=s@entry=0x7fffffffd3b0, 
    format=format@entry=0x4010f8 "%*d%5c%5c%5d %lf %lf %lf %*f %*f %*f\n", 
  argptr=argptr@entry=0x7fffffffd4d8, errp=errp@entry=0x0) at vfscanf.c:343
 #1  0x00007ffff7a72a0c in __GI___isoc99_vsscanf (
     string=0x7fffffffd650 " 4545SOL    HW123234   2.687   0.089   7.120 -1.1448  0.0920  0.6016\n", format=0x4010f8 "%*d%5c%5c%5d %lf %lf %lf %*f %*f %*f\n", 
   args=args@entry=0x7fffffffd4d8) at isoc99_vsscanf.c:43
 #2  0x00007ffff7a72997 in __isoc99_sscanf (s=<optimized out>, 
  format=<optimized out>) at isoc99_sscanf.c:31
 #3  0x0000000000400a9c in read (PMI=0x603490, COION=0x606ce0, 
     COUNTERION=0x60dd70, SOL=0x7ffff7f58010, in=0x603010, out=0x603250)
   at thick_calc.c:97
 #4  0x0000000000400915 in main () at thick_calc.c:52
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are not reassiging the pointer, it should be

   ```
   void main()
   {
      int * array;
      allocation(&array);
      if (array != NULL)
          deallocation(array);
   }

   void allocation(int **result)
   {
      if (result == NULL)
          return;
      *result = malloc(8293 * sizeof(int));
   }

   void deallocation(int * result)
   {
      free(result);
   }
   ```

   by passing the pointer, you can modify it's content, but you cannot change where it points to, so you must pass a pointer to the pointer, i.e. the address to the pointer so you can modify where it points to.

   The problem in your code is that your pointer remains invalid in the scope of main, so when you pass it to `free` it's not actually pointing to the `malloc`ed memory block.
2. Doing that is causes undefined behavior. Reading or writing past the `malloc`ed block causes undefined behavior, so you cannot expect a given behavior, because it's undefined.

   It means, it could cause a Segmentation Fault, or it could work, or anything could happen because it's undefined.

   Eventualy you will write to a special location in memory and something will happen, you can't be sure what is happening meanwhile since again it's undefined behavior.